# Maximum number of allowed datasets in one project

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a limit on how many datasets I can create in one BigQuery project? I did not find this limit anywhere mentioned in documentations.

I am asking this because I want to create a dataset per day. Under the daily dataset, there will be the same number of tables being created with the daily data. E.g.,

```
dataset_20121101
   - table1
   - table2
dataset_20121102
   - table1
   - table2
...
dataset_201XXXXX
   - table1
   - table2
```

Also if I want to do a query over a range of datasets, can I do something better than explicitly selecting from every single dataset? For instance,

```
select date, sum(price) from 
 dateset_20121101.table1, 
 dateset_20121102.table1,
 dateset_20121103.table1,
 dateset_20121104.table1
 group by date order by date
```

I guess not, but just try to confirm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Datasets per project**

There is no hard limit to the amount of BigQuery datasets you can create per project. However, if you have created a huge amount, then this might provide some challenge when trying to list, for example, all programmatically. ALso, having hundreds of datasets might not be very easy to navigate in the BigQuery UI. Note also that it looks like the [bq command line tool](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool) doesn't currently paginate over 50 datasets per project (it only displays the first 50, we'll consider adding pagination functions as a feature request).

**2. Quering over a range of datasets**

Explicitly listing each dataset.table combination is currently the only way to specify a query to be run over a range of datasets. However, improved syntax for referencing multiple tables is a very common developer request, so we are exploring improvements (such as possibly selecting a range of tables via a pattern rather than a list). For announcements about new features, sign up for the [bigquery-announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-announce) list.

Comment: I think there is still a limit for 50. I can not return more than 50 datasets with your ruby client.